# My code works fine when i run this code on apache. But when i implement it on iis, it doesnt work

Tags: php, apache, iis

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "../../lib/mssql.connect.php";


    $params = array($_POST['id']);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adminIP WHERE id = ?";

         //run the query
         $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql,$params);

         while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $id[] = array('id' =>$row['id']);
                $name[] = array('adminname' =>$row['adminName']);
                $ip[] = array('adminip' =>$row['adminIP']);
            }

            ?>      
            <form method = "post" action="">
            <div class="col-lg-10">

 <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtname" value="<? echo implode(",", $name[0]) ?>" disabled="">
</div>                                  <br/>
                                    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">IP</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtip" value="<? echo implode(",", $ip[0]) ?>" data-content="Please enter your IP Address" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtid" value="<? echo implode(",", $id[0]) ?>"style="display: none">
                                    </div>
                            </div>  
            </form>
            <?php
            ?>
```

Comment: Which version of php you are using on iis server ?

Comment: Okay fine. Can you please post the if any error comes when you are running the code. Or try with by putting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);` this code at start of your file.

Comment: @AlankarMore where do i place the error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);? is it at php.ini?

Comment: After session_start(); in your php file not in php.ini.

Comment: It display this on my form.Name
<? echo implode(
" disabled="">
IP 
<? echo implode(
" data-content="Please enter your IP Address" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom"> 
<? echo implode(
"style="display: none"> @AlankarMore

Comment: Any suggestion? @AlankarMore

Comment: Ah the information you have posted is not enough to answer. still try to change this line of code `<? echo implode(",", $name[0]) ?>` with `<?php echo implode(",", $name[0]) ?>` Might it resolves your problem.

Comment: Because the code was working fine when i run my site on apache, but when i run it on IIS it doesnt work. @AlankarMore